# Rails join and count

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm relatively new to Rails (Rails 4).
So I have a table `talent_media` that has `talent_id` and `media_id` attributes.

The same `media_id` will appear many times.
Kanye (`talent_id`)  might like 20 different songs (`media_id`) and each is in it's own row for instance.
I also have a `Media` table that has various rows.
I need to find the top 100 `talent_media` entries based on the `media_id` row and join that with the `Media` table based on the `media.id` row. So in essence I get the most popular songs in the `talent_media` table and then join them to return the actual media info from the `Media` table.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can query your `TalentMedia` model to get the results..

```
@top_100 = TalentMedia.includes(:media).select(:media_id).order('count(talent_id) desc').group(:media_id).limit(100)
```

Then, you can display each of them looping over it like,

```
@top_100.each do |topper|
  topper.media.name
end
```

Comment: Hmm that didn't seem to work:
'Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'media.talent_medium_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `media`.* FROM `media` WHERE `media`.`talent_medium_id` IN ('')):'

Comment: ohh, might have missed something, can you post what sql query does it generate? use `.to_sql` `TalentMedia.includes(:media).select(:media_id).order('count(talent_id) desc').group(:media_id).to_sql`